# Programmatically clicking on dataGridView header cells

Tags: c#, gridview-sorting

How can I programmatically perform click on a certain dataGridView column header? I want to have the data sorted, but the when I sort the data using SQL ORDER BY I get some weird results (I think it is because the data has some Croatian letters as starting chars). However, the dataGridView sorts it correctly when I click on the column header. So how can I do that automatically on display?
Thanks

Comment: You dont need to perform click event. You can simply Sort by partucular column when ever you want to do so. Or not?

Comment: Yes, I found it, I should google before I post in future :D Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datagridview.sort(DataGridviewColumn column, System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection direction);
```

code to sort a datagridview by column and direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [DataGridView sort method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort.aspx)